# How to keep verbosity when sourcing from a bash script

Tags: bash

I need to check the run of a bash script, with a source call, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
some code here
source script_b.sh
more code here
```

I run:

```
$bash -x script_a.sh
```

and I get,

```
+ some echo here
+ script_b.sh
+ some more echo here
```

But all echoes are from script_a.sh. All the code from script_b.sh is hidden, so I can not trace what is really happening.

Is there any way I can check the execution of script_b.sh within script_a.sh?

Comment: It works as you want for me. I'm using bash 3.2.48.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, my version os higher. I tried to reproduce the problem  with a simple script, and indeed it works. Strange. I'll follow the tip from below.

Comment: I just tried it in bash 4.1.5 and it worked as well.

Comment: This might be answered at http://serverfault.com/questions/16204/how-to-make-bash-scripts-print-out-every-command-before-it-executes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try "bash -x script_b.sh" inside of the parent script.

Edit:

This worked for me. If you run the parent script with bash -x you will see everything for both. "set -x" will set the debug flag for the environment...in the script? I'm not sure, and fifo is still magic to me.

```
echo "start of script"
set -x
mkfifo fifo
cat /dev/null < fifo | fifo > source .bash_profile
rm fifo
echo "end of script"
```

Comment: That will run the script in a subshell. Usually you source a script because you need it to make changes to the original shell's environment.

Comment: Right, but for debugging it might be a hacky way to see what is happening. What about using "strace ./script_a.sh"?